# Tried converting sql query to linq, however, I get different results

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert an sql statement to linq, but maybe I am doing something wrong because I'm getting different results. I am trying my linq statement in LinqPad.

**Here is my sql statment:**

```
SELECT set_id
        FROM TestTable
        WHERE rec_id In (25,32)
        AND set_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT x.set_id FROM TestTable x
        WHERE x.rec_id NOT IN(25,32)
        )
        GROUP BY set_id
        HAVING COUNT(set_id) = 2
```

**Linq statment:**

```
var recIdList = new List<int?>() { 25,32};

var query = from u in TestTables
                            where
                            (
                                recIdList.Contains(u.Rec_id) &&
                                !(from k in TestTables
                                  where !recIdList.Contains(u.Rec_id)
                                  select k.Set_id).Contains(u.Set_id)
                            )
                            group u by u.Set_id into userGroup
                            where userGroup.Count() == recIdList.Count
                            select userGroup.Key;
query.Dump();
TestTables.Dump();
```

The sql query generated by Linq:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 25
DECLARE @p1 Int = 32
DECLARE @p2 Int = 25
DECLARE @p3 Int = 32
DECLARE @p4 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[set_id]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[set_id]
    FROM [TestTable] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[rec_id] IN (@p0, @p1)) AND (NOT (EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [TestTable] AS [t1]
        WHERE ([t1].[set_id] = [t0].[set_id]) AND (NOT ([t0].[rec_id] IN (@p2, @p3)))
        )))
    GROUP BY [t0].[set_id]
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE [t2].[value] = @p4
```

TestTable:

```
Create Table TestTable
(
  set_id int,
  rec_id int
)
Insert Into TestTable (set_id, rec_id) Values(10, 1)
Insert Into TestTable (set_id, rec_id) Values(10, 25)
Insert Into TestTable (set_id, rec_id) Values(10, 32)
Insert Into TestTable (set_id, rec_id) Values(20, 61)
Insert Into TestTable (set_id, rec_id) Values(20, 90)
Insert Into TestTable (set_id, rec_id) Values(30, 77)
Insert Into TestTable (set_id,rec_id)  Values(11,25)
Insert Into TestTable (set_id,rec_id)  Values(11,32)

GO
```

The result for my Sql query: set_id 11 
The result for my Linq query: set_id (10 and 11)

The idea is I am trying to get the set_id where the the rec_id is exactly (set_id 11: (25,32)), however (set_id 10: (1,25,32)) is not an exact match.

I've added two images that shows the result set for both using LinqPad:

[SqlStatmentWithResultSet](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=3A6FFF199D5185F9&id=3A6FFF199D5185F9!151&sc=photos)

[LinqStatmentWihtResultSet](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=3a6fff199d5185f9#!/?cid=3a6fff199d5185f9&sc=photos&uc=2&id=3A6FFF199D5185F9!150!cid=3A6FFF199D5185F9&id=3A6FFF199D5185F9!152&sc=photos)

Thanks in advance for you help...

Comment: In your LINQ statement, in the subquery, you have "!recIdList.Contains(u.Rec_id)". Should this not be testing for k.Rec_id?

Comment: How can I mark the question as answered ???
This is my second questio in stackoverflow :O

Comment: I posted it as an answer now, since it did actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your LINQ statement, in the subquery, you have "!recIdList.Contains(u.Rec_id)". Should this not be testing for k.Rec_id?